# Drupal Acquia Stack - Have moved files to different folder, how to update site?

Tags: drupal, acquia

Im using the Acquia stack instead of MAMP or WAMP but im using it to run a normal Drupal installation.

I imported a site fine. Ive then moved the sites's files to a different folder, and now I cant figure out how to change the site's settings.

In the stack interface, if I go to my site and click settings > Sites > Edit 
Then I can see the Site Path that it points to the old folder, but I cant change these settings.

Do I need to create a new site and import it again? 
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was looking for this answer, and digged out into acquia install folder. Here is what I did to change Site Path at acquia desktop interface.

Don't forget to make a backup just in case.

There are 4 files to attend to:

1. Open and edit static.ini and dynamic.ini under your AcquiaDevDesktopControlPanel at Program Files/acquia-drupal install folder. Maybe different on Mac.
2. Edit siteDir at static.ini
3. Edit selImportedSiteCodebase and codebaseDir at dynamic.ini
4. Edit httpd.conf at apache folder to use your new document root. There are 3 or 4 locations to change there
5. Edit vhosts.conf to reflect your new locations

You have to run the notepad as administrator.

Its seems that changing only #4 + #5 don't hurt my sites, these can be done via acquia interface. But changing #2 + #3 makes you feel comfortable :)

Hope that helps

Comment: I am using the Acquia dev desktop 2 beta. I only wanted to change the site URL, and I only had to edit the datamodel.xml file in %PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Dev Desktop\AcquiaDevDesktop\

Comment: I also had to change the hosts file entry, and the vhosts file in dev desktop\apache\conf\vhosts.conf

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question. I'm running Acquia Dev Desktop and wanted to change the default folder of the installation from /drupal-7.10 to /docroot.

I'm running this on a Mac and after reading the posts above, I searched for the dynamic.ini and static.ini files which were not to be found on my harddrive. Checked the httpd.conf file and didn't see anything mentioned.

I ended up making a backup copy of vhosts.conf and changed vhosts.conf to:

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName loc.MYWEBSITE.com
  DocumentRoot "/Users/dv/Sites/MYWEBSITE/**new_dir_name**
  <Directory "/Users/dv/Sites/MYWEBSITE/**new_dir_name**">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory<
<VirtualHost>
```

Refreshed the browser and I was good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem as well, the only way I was able to remedy was to dump the database delete the project, then re-import. Just an FYI, make sure that the settings.php in Drupal are set up correctly for the localhost setup, this was another snafoo for me.

.. I looked all around the Acquia files to try to find a place where it was storing this information first but could not find it

Answer (score 0):

In .htaccess, is the RewriteBase line pointing to the right directory? Ex:

```
 RewriteBase /new/directory/
```

Comment: The RewriteBase stuff is commented out. When Ive moved drupal installations before (around my computer and also up to a server) ive never changed the .htaccess settings and everything has always worked fine. Does Acquia stack edit the .htaccess? If so, why? Thanks

Comment: Be default, the RewriteBase line is commented out and is usually not needed.  In my experience, I needed it when my Drupal installation was not in the the folder of the apache root directory.  That is, if my website was mapped to the directory /htdocs, and my drupal installation was in /htdocs/drupal, then I would need to uncomment the RewriteBase line and add the drupal folder to it.  However, if my website was mapped to /htdocs/drupal as the root then there is no need to uncomment the line.

Comment: I dont imagine this is the problem as the Acquia stack interface lists the site's old location on my computer but wont let me change this setting. Thanks

Comment: Still searching to locate files to change old Site Path too. Strangely my sites are working fine after changing httpd.conf and its vhosts file. The only problem, which is not causing a real problem, yet, is that acquia Site Path still points to old install folder. Maybe its somewhere in .exe file. I haven't tried to reinstalled because I am working with SVN for both old and new folders.

Answer (score 0):

You'll also need to edit the - C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts - file to update any entries

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X you will need to find and edit paths in the following files:

```
~/.acquia/DevDesktop/locations.ini
~/.acquia/DevDesktop/Drush/Aliases/aliases.drushrc.php
/Applications/DevDesktop/apache/conf/vhosts.conf
/Applications/DevDesktop/apache/conf/httpd.conf
```

and, most importantly, in the DevDesktop package itself:

1. In `/Applications/DevDesktop` - right-click Acquia Dev Desktop
2. Select "Show Package Contents"
3. Edit `datamodel.xml` and `static.ini`